# What is the best code to suit this operation?

Tags: python

Just started working with python, less than one week. And this exercise came in. I managed to find this code online and I started to get the hand of it:

"A snail falls at the bottom of a 125 cm well. Each day the snail rises 30 cm. But at night, while sleeping, slides 20 cm because the walls are wet. How many days does it take to escape from the well?

-Assign problem data to variables with representative names
well height, daily advance, night retreat, accumulated distance

```
well_height = 125

daily_advance = 30

night_retreat = -20

accumulated_distance = daily_advance + night_retreat

totalcms = 0
```

-Assign 0 to the variable that represents the solution

```
days = 0
```

-Write the code that solves the problem

```
snailhasnotescaped = True
while snailhasnotescaped:
    totalcms += accumulated_distance
    days += 1
if totalcms >= well_height:
snailhasnotescaped = False
```

-Print the result with print('Days =', days)

```
print("Days = ", days, "days")"
```

Now its asking me this set of questions:

The distance traveled by the snail is now defined by a list.

```
advance_cm = [30, 21, 33, 77, 44, 45, 23, 45, 12, 34, 55]
```

How long does it take to raise the well?
What is its maximum displacement in one day? And its minimum?
What is its average speed during the day?
What is the standard deviation of its displacement during the day?

Could someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question may be a personal exercise, but it still reads like homework. Please consider this post to enhance the reception of your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: `totalcms += accumulated_distance` This is wrong, because eventually the snail will reach the top of the well and escape, and thus will not slide back.

Comment: _What is its maximum displacement in one day? And its minimum?_ You can use `max()` and `min()` to get the largest and smallest values in a list.

Comment: If it is wrong, what would be the best code? 
This is for learning purposes, I am trying to get the hand of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, imagine if the snake has 15 cm to go before reaching the top on day X. Will he reach the top of the well? Obviously, since he advances 30cm BEFORE falling back 20cm. Be careful, your code doesn't take this into account. I would do something like this:

```py
day = 1
while True:
    totalcms += daily_advance

    if totalcms >= well_height:
        break

    totalcms -= night_retreat
    day += 1

print(day)
```

Be aware that `while True` is a **bad** practice. It is only okay if you are SURE you will break out the loop. You could add a condition here to verify that the snake does go forward before entering the loop. You could instead decide that you go down before going up in the day and do `while totalcms < well_height`.

You could also wrap everything around a function to be able to use it more efficiently.

The next question is ambiguous. Is it an advance rate per day? If yes, instead of a while loop, just iterate through the list (it even resolves our problem). For the other questions, I'm sure you can figure it out!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
well_height = 125

daily_advance = 30

night_retreat = -20

accumulated_distance = daily_advance + night_retreat

totalcms = 0

days=0

snailhasnotescaped = True
while snailhasnotescaped:
    totalcms += daily_advance
    if totalcms >= well_height:
        snailhasnotescaped = False
        break

    days += 1

    totalcms += night_retreat
    if totalcms >= well_height:
        snailhasnotescaped = False
        break


print(days)
```

you can try :

```
from statistics import mean,stdev
well_height = 125

daily_advance = 30

night_retreat = -20


advance_cm = [30, 21, 33, 77, 44, 45, 23, 45, 12, 34, 55]

accumulated_distance = daily_advance + night_retreat

totalcms = 0

days=0
count=0

snailhasnotescaped = True
while snailhasnotescaped:
    totalcms += advance_cm[count]
    if totalcms >= well_height:
        snailhasnotescaped = False
        break

    days += 1

    totalcms += night_retreat
    if totalcms >= well_height:
        snailhasnotescaped = False
        break
    count+=1



print(days)

print("max distance in day=",max(advance_cm))
print("min distance in day=",min(advance_cm))
print("avg distance in day=",mean(advance_cm))
print("standard deviation distance in day=",stdev(advance_cm))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the code you've got:

```
snailhasnotescaped = True
while snailhasnotescaped:
    totalcms += accumulated_distance
    days += 1
    if totalcms >= well_height:
        snailhasnotescaped = False
```

As you are now, `accumulated_distance` is constant. You set it to `accumulated_distance = daily_advance + night_retreat` in advance. With the new problem you've been given, that's not going to work. So, here is how to adjust your solution to fit your new problems, in order:

---

> How long does it take to raise the well?

Instead of calculating `accumulated_distance` all at once, you'll need to calculate it for each individual day:

```
for day_cm in advance_cm:
    days += 1
    totalcms += day_cm  # add however much it travels that day
    if totalcms >= well_height:
        break  # just stop the for loop immediately - we've escaped, therefore we already know what `days` is supposed to be
    totalcms -= night_retreat  # If we didn't escape, then we'll lose 20cm overnight
```

If the days in `advance_cm` aren't enough, then you can check that after the loop finishes:

```
if totalcms < well_height:
    # do something
```

---

> What is its maximum displacement in one day?

Well, you know how far it travels each day - you just need to find the greatest distance in one day. Python has a built-in function to do this for you easily:

```
max_displacement = max(advance_cm)
```

Alternatively, if falling backwards at night counts towards total displacement, you might want to change your loop to make a new list of displacements:

```
displacements = []
for day_cm in advance_cm:
    days += 1
    totalcms += day_cm
    displacements.append(day_cm)  # how much did we move during the day
    if totalcms >= well_height:
        break
    totalcms -= night_retreat
    displacements[-1] -= night_retreat  # remove our fall distance from the last element of the list, where we put how much we moved during the day
```

And then we can take the maximum displacement from that:

```
max_displacement = max(displacements)
```

---

> What is its average speed during the day?
>
> What is the standard deviation of its displacement during the day?

Well, you should know how to calculate averages. Python has a built-in `sum()` function to take the sum of all elements in a list, which makes this easy:

```
avg_speed = sum(displacements) / days  # unit: cm per day
```

As for standard deviation, that's a bit trickier - you'd need to know the standard deviation formula and calculate it. Thankfully, python's standard library includes the `statistics` package, which can do that for you!

```
import statistics
...
std_dev = statistics.stdev(displacements)
```

Comment: boredom, mostly. I also feel like it's useless to provide code as an answer without explaining *why* - you know, the whole "give a man a fish / teach a man to fish" thing.

Comment: Put `>` at the start of the line. It's the markdown syntax for "quoted block of text" or something like that